# Virtualenv: global site-packages vs the site-packages in the virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

1. If I have a certain package installed both in the global site-packages and in the local one, which package will get imported? Will that even work or will I get an error?
2. Which packages should I put in the global site-packages and which in the local one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The previous answer wraps up question 1 but ignores question 2.

The general best practice I've seen for which packages to put globally:

First, the core Python packages, as these don't change with backwards-incompatible issues unless you're upgrading a major version, and you'll want whatever security fixes from a python upgrade to apply automatically to your virtualenvs.

Second, packages that are a pain to easy_install or pip install into each individual virtualenv but that don't change very often -- MySQLdb/psycopg and PIL, for example.

Pretty much everything else should go into your virtualenv's packages (I highly recommend using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) requirements files and [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) to make this minimally painful and easy to set up on other machines).

Answer (score 3):

Newly created virtual environment by default have access to global site-packages directory, unless created with --no-site-packages. Calling easy_install (installing new packages) with certain environment activated will cause local overwrite of already existing ones in global site-packages (similar to inheritance). Environment will use its own local packages, when missing - global ones.

Comment: *Newly created virtual environment by default have access to global site-packages directory* This is no longer true.